# Why will nothing paint on my screen?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, draw, paint

I am working on a 2D platformer using swing in java, and I am currently developing the framework for the game. I am testing the reapaint() and draw functions, but they do not function and I am clueless. Here is my code:

Window.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Window extends JFrame {

public Window() {

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(1000, 1000);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setTitle("Infiltrator");
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setContentPane(new Framework());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    { 
    @Override
    public void run() 
    { new Window(); } 
    }
                                             );

}





}
```

Panel.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public abstract class Panel extends JPanel {

public Panel() {

this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
this.setFocusable(true);

/*
 * 
if(false)
{
    BufferedImage blankCursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(blankCursorImg, new Point(0, 0), null);
    this.setCursor(blankCursor);
}
*
*/
}

public static void Draw(Graphics2D g2d) {

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;        
super.paintComponent(g2d);        
Framework.Draw(g2d);    
}

}
```

Framework.java

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Framework extends Panel {

private static long beginTime, takenTime, sleepTime;
private static long secInNano = 1000000000L;
private static long secInMilli = 1000000L;
private static long fps = 60L;
private static long fpsTime = secInNano / fps;

public static enum GameState {STARTING, MAINMENU, PLAYING, OVER};
public static GameState gameState;

public Framework ()
{
    super();

    Thread gameThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            mainLoop();
        }
    };

    gameState = GameState.STARTING;

    gameThread.start();
}

private void mainLoop() {

    while (gameState != GameState.OVER) {

        beginTime = System.nanoTime();

        switch (gameState) {
            case STARTING:  
                LoadandInit();
                break;
            case MAINMENU: 
                MainMenu.Update();
                break;
            case PLAYING: 

                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Ok, somebody messed up.");
                break;

        }

        repaint();

        takenTime = System.nanoTime() - beginTime;
        sleepTime = (fpsTime - takenTime) / secInMilli;
        if (sleepTime < 10)
            sleepTime = 10;

        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }


    }


}



private static void LoadandInit() {

    gameState = GameState.MAINMENU;
}


public static void Draw(Graphics2D g2d) {

        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.drawString("DEARP", 0, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: Too many static methods/variables for me to understand what is going on. Using static usually means a design problem. I suggest you start with the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the basics.

Comment: Does it fall into infinite loop? try to remove `super.paingComponent()` from your `paintComponent` implementation.

Comment: @Antoniossss, you should always invoke super.paintComponent() to make sure the background of the panel is painted. It will not cause a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding an instance of Framework to your Window, but framework doesn't override paintCompontents.  It has a static Draw method which is called by Panel, but you never create an instance of panel.

You could convert your Draw method to paintComponent(), and delete you're Panel class.

Also you should not start your thread inside the constructor for Framework.  This can cause the run method to see the incorrect values for member variables.  Create a new start method that starts a thread.

Comment: I hope you wanted to write `paintComponent()` :-)

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend chapter 2 of Killer Game Programming in Java. You can read a draft of the chapter on the book's website:

http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/ch1/index.html

Comment: Links are not answers.  At best, this is a comment.

Comment: No good deed goes unpunished I guess. The chapter is 27 pages long, I can't summarize that in an answer.

Comment: If this were posted as a comment, i'd upvote it.  But [it's not an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: You don't need to summarize the whole thing.  The OP has a specific problem; it doesn't take a whole book (or even a whole chapter) to explain what that problem is.

Comment: You down vote for providing a relevant link that would give them a quality animation framework as well as an explanation of how that framework works? I reserve down votes for information that is just plain wrong or misleading.

Comment: I reserve downvotes for information that is unhelpful in the context in which it is provided.  As i said, you're not answering the question being asked.  You could easily suggest the book in a comment...but it's not an answer, as it does not even *begin* to explain the actual problem the OP is having at this moment.  It'd be like handing a cookbook to someone who constantly burns their cookies.  Might help in the long run, but it's worthless *right now*.